# Can we boost the performance of COUNT, DISTINCT and LIKE queries?

Tags: performance, postgresql, count, distinct, sql-like

As far as I understand, when we run SQL query with `COUNT`, `DISTINCT` or `LIKE %query%` (wildcards at both sides) keywords the indexes cannot be used and the database have to do the full table scan.

Is there some way to boost the performance of these queries?

Do they really cannot use indexes or we can fix this somehow?

Can we make an index-only scan if we need to return only one column? For example: `select count(id) from MY_TABLE`: probably in this case we can make index-only scan and avoid hitting the whole table if we have index on 'id'?

My question has a general meaning: could you give me some performance guidelines if we have to use the mentioned operators?

UPDATE
As for me I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: What RDBMS? SQL Server would use a narrower index on `id` (if available) for `select count(id) from MY_TABLE`

Comment: And even without any condition, a `SELECT DISTINCT a,b FROM t;` would use an index on `(a,b)` or `(b,a)`

Comment: On what database platform?  For example, Postgres has an extension called [Wildspeed](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/wildspeed) that lets you index `LIKE` queries.

Comment: ypercube, I try to run query which would use index in the simpliest case: select distinct column_name from MY_TABLE but I fail. It uses index only in case of 2 columns?

Comment: Here's [some info](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) on Postgres row counting and indexes - it addresses your question on why `select count(*) from table;` can't use an index.

Comment: No, that was just an example. If the index matches what you have in the select, it should be used. Unless of course (add a hundred exceptions here, like): Is the table too small? What datatype is `column_name`? Which Postgres version?

Comment: Postgres can use an index for `like '%foo%'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Out of the box?  Since when?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: with a special index: http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Way cool!

Answer (score 0):

with PostgreSQL, you can create GIN pg_trgm indexes for text strings to make LIKE '%foo%' faster, though this requires addons, and PostgreSQL 9.1 or higher.

I doubt distinct by itself will ever use an index.  I tried in fact and could not get it to use one.   You can sort of force an index to be used by using a recursive CTE to pull individual records out (what can be called a "sparse scan").  We do something like this when pulling individual years out of the accounting record.  This requires writing special queries though and so isn't really the general case.

count(*) is never going to be able to use an index due to mvcc rules.  You can get approximate results by looking in the appropriate system catalogs however.